# How to swap the imported class easily?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Let's suppose you wrote the code:

```
Supplier<Boolean> supplier = () -> true;
```

However, if you have Guava on your classpath, then there are two implementations of `Supplier` - from `com.google.common.base` and `java.util.function`.

How to easily change the imported class from one to another in IntelliJ?

The question is not about the `Supplier` class. It's about the general problem of accidentally importing not-the-right implementation. Currently, in such cases I go to the imports on the top of the file, removes the wrong import, hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose the right one. I'm sure you know a faster method!

Comment: In Eclipse, when completing the class name, if there is ambiguity you are asked which implementation you want... (before the imports have been automatically set). Intellij doesn't ask, in this case?

Comment: It asks but who cares. It knows better, enter! :-)

Comment: Deleting the bad import and re-importing the correct one is the only way I know how.  Can't really get much easier than that now can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice it immediately after you add, you could just invoke Undo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. But you know that of course.

In case you always want one class and (almost) never the other, you could exclude one of the classes from auto-import. Press <kbd>►</kbd> (right arrow key) in the `Class to Import` popup and choose one of the `Exclude '...' from auto-import` options.
And if you make a mistake, you can remove classes from the `Exclude from Import and Completion` list in 
`File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import`.

Comment: This is helpful, indeed. I knew I can exclude some classes from import but I didn't know I can do it while choosing one of them. Thank you.

Comment: After two weeks of excluding ridiculous import suggestions I can tell it solved my problem definitely. Thank you again!